# Android - Ellipsize with right aligned view

Tags: android, layout, alignment

How can I achieve the following layout, with TextView being a `TextView` with ellipsize end and View being `wrap_content` and immediately to the right of TextView ?

Here are three examples of how the layout should behave, with different TextView width :

```
|[TextView] [View]              |

|[TextView TextView] [View]     |

|[TextView TextView T...] [View]|
```

[Edit]

The following `TableLayout` gives the correct behaviour :

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/upper_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/alert_button"
    android:shrinkColumns="0"
    android:stretchColumns="2" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lines="1"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unread_count_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The `TableLayout` uses 3 columns, the last being the hack : the `strechColumns` property makes it take all available space, so the second `TextView` is always immediatly to the right of the first one.
The first `TextView` ellipsize correctly because of the `shrinkColumns` property.

However, I don't like the idea of using a `TableLayout` to achieve that.
Does anybody know a better way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I cannot check it now, but to my point of view it should work):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_txtvw_txtvw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/my_txtvw_txtvw"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately with this solution the right TextView gets pushed off the screen when the left TextView is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/my_view"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="blablabla blablabla"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not sure if you want `android:ellipsize="end"` or `android:ellipsize="marquee"`. I think the layout will work fine to you, just replace the ellipsize value id needed.

Let me know about your progress...

Comment: Thanks yugidroid for your answer.
You put `alignParentRight="true"` on the second view. The problem is that the view will always be aligned to the far right. 
I want "my_view" to be just to the right of "text1". Once the first TextView ("text1") is too long to fit inside the parent, "my_view" is aligned right and "text1" is ellipsized.
Removing `alignParentRight="true"` did not help because "text1" is pushed off screen to the left by my_view.